# Running test cases in parallel in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, selenium, testing, intellij-idea

I have test cases that I would them to run in parallel. What I've done was created a *Compound* run configuration where I inputed all of my TestNG. After running the Compound configuration I've noticed that all the test cases run at the same time. I would like to know if this considered running them in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Compound configuration* by default will launch at once all your TestNG.

To launch configurations sequentially you can try [Multirun plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun). It runs multiple Run Configurations simultaneously, but just add the default (empty) Multirun configuration and queue up other tasks to run sequentially through the Before launch section.